# std::vector constructor with allocator argument

Tags: c++

I'm trying out vector and [its constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector). On *[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com)*, the second constructor is listed as:

```cpp
constexpr explicit vector(const Allocator& alloc) noexcept;
```

and I couldn't figured out how to use it. I know I can use my own allocator, like:

```cpp
std::vector<int, myAllocator<int>> iv;
```

but I wondered what is the use case for passing allocator as an argument for it. Maybe something like:

```cpp
myallocator<int> ia;
std::vector<int, decltype(ia)> iv(ia);
```

I don't know what I'm missing, any tips are welcome.

Comment: Allocators can have state.  You might one to pass one that has some preset state for the vector to use.

Comment: Consider an allocator that redistributes an preallocated pool of memory. Each instance of such an allocator could have a different memory pool. This makes the allocator stateful, and it means a default constructed allocator is probably not useful, you need to be able to provide it with the preallocated memory. This overload allows you to use such an allocator. You first construct the allocator, then you can pass it to the vector's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

> but I wondered what is the use case for passing allocator as an
> argument for it. Maybe something like:
>
> ```
> myallocator<int> ia;
> std::vector<int, decltype(ia)> iv(ia);
> ```

Yes, that is how you pass an instance of the allocator into the mentioned constructor. That said, the non-allocator constructor value initialises the allocator, so there won't be a difference beyond the extra copying that your example does.